# Aligning two elements in a container using css?

Tags: html, css

I like to make my navigation bar and header all the same, but I can't get the navigation bar to align properly. Using `float: right` doesn't work, as it appears to take it out of the container (if that makes sense)

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/AVY7T/228/

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AVY7T/229/? Oh, and always post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: It's because the card header div is a block element so it spans 100% width and pushes the navigation down. If you put the navigation inside that div it will help. You should also research [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html) which is good for floated elements.

Comment: What does "all the same" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `float: right` to your  element? As you said, floating will make the parent element ignore the element height, which places the element outside the parent. Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent element, in this case the header class, will solve the problem.

Updated JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/AVY7T/231/

Placing both elements on the same row:

https://jsfiddle.net/AVY7T/232/

Comment: That's perfect, but I'd still like them both to be on the same line, rather than having the navigation be below the title

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of your question ;) Just wrap the left side in a div, and make it float left. I'll update my JSFiddle.